# AddDistributedSqlServerCache, multiple Applications, same Table

Tags: .net-core

My .NET Core website will probably soon-ish migrate to a webserver farm for continued uptime, even during maintenance.

I currently identified the following steps to change in my website:

- **`services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache()`**
- `services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext()`
- `services.AddDataProtection().ProtectKeysWithCertificate()`
- set same MachineKey for all instances.

Question: For the boldly printed `AddDistributedSqlServerCache()`, can I utilize the **same** database table for multiple websites? Or does every website need its own table?
If relevant: all websites are protected by the same OIDC central login server (+ said central login server itself).

Bonus Question: If the SQL-Server is made into a cluster for higher availability, do I need to change anything in my website itself or in the connection string? Or are the specifics of the cluster vs. single instance invisible from the viewpoint of my website?

The website is currently still running under .NET Core 2.1, there was no time yet to upgrade to .NET 6. `PersistKeysToDbContext()` was backported from the implementation in https://source.dot.net/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple applications can use the same session table in SQL Server for session state management.

When using AddDistributedSqlServerCache in multiple applications, you can configure them to share the same session table by specifying the same SchemaName and TableName values in the configuration. By doing this, all the applications will store and retrieve session data from the same table in the SQL Server database.

***Nonetheless, caution should be exercised when considering this approach, as sharing the cache table among multiple applications may give rise to additional complexities. It is advisable to employ separate tables for each application instead.***